# Ordenar datos en bipartited3

Tags: r, r-bipartite

Dado el siguiente código:

```
prueba<-read.csv("matriz_prueba.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")
head(prueba)

  PAIS_ORIGEN     AFG     ETH     TZA     PAK     VNM
1         USA 6686.77 1726.46  834.16 2044.88  192.19
2          EU  609.50  396.27  298.63  244.11   84.17
3         IDA  424.68 1637.79 1461.09 1150.64 1939.73
4         FRA   95.65   45.01   26.00   20.54  341.29
5         JPN  867.20  154.99  182.21  272.97 1622.79
6         DEU  754.42  164.52  207.36  233.14  194.22

str(prueba)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ PAIS_ORIGEN: chr  "USA" "EU" "IDA" "FRA" ...
 $ AFG        : num  6686.8 609.5 424.7 95.7 867.2 ...
 $ ETH        : num  1726 396 1638 45 155 ...
 $ TZA        : num  834 299 1461 26 182 ...
 $ PAK        : num  2044.9 244.1 1150.6 20.5 273 ...
 $ VNM        : num  192.2 84.2 1939.7 341.3 1622.8 ...

rownames(prueba) <- prueba$PAIS_ORIGEN datos 
prueba <- prueba[,2:6]
prueba1<- as.matrix(prueba)
prueba_df<-Matrix2DF(prueba1)
bipartite_D3(prueba_df,PrimaryLab='Donor', SecondaryLab = 'Recipient', SiteNames='ODA',
             MainFigSize = c(800, 1500), 
             IndivFigSize = c(200, 600),
             BoxLabPos = c(20, 20),
             PercPos = c(200,200),
             BarSize = 20,
             MinWidth = 5,
             Pad=5,
             PercentageDecimals = 2)
```

Obteniendo el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna manera de poder ordenar los datos "Donor" y "Recipient" de mayor a menor porcentaje? He visto la siguiente información pero no he sido capaz de aplicarlo a mis datos: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bipartiteD3/vignettes/bipartiteD3_Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

La función bipartite_D3 cuenta con dos parámetros que te permite ordenar los porcentajes que se muestran dentro de la función te comparto como se realizaría con los datos muestras

```
library(dplyr)
library(bipartite)
library(bipartiteD3)

prueba<-data.frame(PAIS_ORIGEN=c("USA","EU","IDA","FRA","JPN","DEU"),
               AFG=c(6686.77,609.5,424.68,95.65,867.2,754.42),
               ETH=c(1726.46,396.27,1637.79,45.01,154.99,164.52),
               TZA=c(834.16,298.63,1461.09,26,182.21,207.36),
               PAK=c(2044.88,244.11,1150.64,20.54,272.97,233.14),
               VNM=c(192.19,84.17,1939.73,341.29,1622.79,194.22))

  rownames(prueba) <- prueba$PAIS_ORIGEN 
  prueba <- prueba[,2:6]
  prueba1<- as.matrix(prueba)
  prueba_df<-Matrix2DF(prueba1)

#Ordenamos la variable de Mayor a Menor
  Primary_ordenado <- prueba_df %>% group_by(Primary) %>%
  summarise(Total=sum(Site)) %>%
  arrange(desc(Total))

#Mostramos los datos ordenados   
print(Primary_ordenado)

 # A tibble: 6 x 2
 Primary  Total
 <chr>    <dbl>
1 USA     11484.
2 IDA      6614.
3 JPN      3100.
4 EU       1633.
5 DEU      1554.
6 FRA       528. 

 #Ordenamos los valores secundarios 
      secundary_ordenado<-prueba_df %>% group_by(Secondary) %>%
      summarise(Total=sum(Site)) %>%
      arrange(desc(Total))

 #mostrmos los datos ya ordenados
     Secondary Total
  <chr>     <dbl>
 1 AFG       9438.
 2 VNM       4374.
 3 ETH       4125.
 4 PAK       3966.
 5 TZA       3009.

 #Utilizamos los parámetros SortPrimary y SortSecondary y los vectores creados 
  anteriormente para así indicarle el orden
  bipartite_D3(prueba_df,SortPrimary = Primary_ordenado$Primary,           
  SortSecondary =secundary_ordenado$Secondary  ,                     
  PrimaryLab='Donor',         
  SecondaryLab = 'Recipient', 
  SiteNames='ODA',
         MainFigSize = c(800, 1500), 
         IndivFigSize = c(200, 600),
         BoxLabPos = c(20, 20),
         PercPos = c(200,200),
         BarSize = 20,
         MinWidth = 5,
         Pad=5,
         PercentageDecimals = 2)
```

Y el resultado que obtenemos es el siguiente : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Sería posible dividir el gráfico en 2 mitades según los valores secundarios? Es decir, tener 2 gráficos donde los primarios sigan mostrándose todos y el secundario solo se muestren una mitad u otra.

Gracias!